# Kanban Board TFS 2013: Show work item ID

Tags: tfs, scrum, workitem, kanban

I'm trying to change the look of the Kanban Board in TFS 2013 by adding the WorkItem ID to tasks, bugs and PBI's.

To be more precise: I would like to add the WI# before the title of each item in the swimminglanes.

I'm trying to do this with witadmin but can't seem to find the correct files.

Comment: The correct answer should be updated as the scenario has changed with a new release of TFS Online. This is now possible to solve.

Comment: The correct anwser still exists as the question is about TFS 2013 which still does not support this.

Comment: Ah, your are correct. Hopefully you get an update for TFS on-prem that supports this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something that you can currently customize through the process template (witadmin). Sorry.

Comment: Note that this is currently an option in TFS 2015.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available on TFS Online.

To show WorkItem Id's on BLI's & Bugs, you have update the settings on the board.

1. Click on the Settings wheel on the top right corner of the board.
   [image]
2. Select "Cards" in the drop down.
3. In the "Customize Cards" page, select the "Show ID" checkbox as highlighted in the below image.
   [image]
4. Click "Save" button. You board will refresh with new settings.

Note: The settings are separate for Bug & Product Backlog Item

Comment: where I can find that "Settings Wheel"?

Comment: See the image in below link. I have highlighted in yellow in the image. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JCtM6nKd9QM1FFM1ZSTjJlbG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sundeep is correct about being able to do this now in Visual Studio Online  (June 2015) and it will be available in TFS 2015 (on-prem), but you still cannot do this in TFS 2013 as per the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can provide at the moment is to point you towards Tiago Pascoal's Task Board Enhancer, which is a extension that can be installed on your TFS server to get some kanban board enhancements.

http://pascoal.net/task-board-enhancer/

As Andrew mentioned, there is no other way to enhance work items on the kanban board currently.

Comment: I understand your anwser but I'm don't want to add a blackbox plugin (which is said to use undocumented features of TFS) with to much functionality. Hopefully someone can explain how to just add the number.

Comment: Well, Pascoal is the best person who would know how to do it, and if he would not use undocumented features of TFS to do it if he didn't have to. I think you're only option is to put the WI# in the title because there is no documented way to add this to TFS otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution of using a "bookmarklet" to just show the ID on the boards without having to make any changes on the server http://pascoal.net/2012/08/adding-work-item-ids-to-team-foundation-server-board/

The one I use is from that site:

```
javascript:$('.tbTile').each(function(){var t=this.id.substring(5,999),n=$(this).find('.witTitle').first();n.attr('_wi')===undefined&&(n.attr('_wi',t),n.html('<strong>'+t+'<\/strong>-'+n.text()))}),$('.board-tile').each(function(){var t=this.id,n=$(this).find('.title').first();n.attr('_wi')===undefined&&(n.attr('_wi',t),n.html('<strong>'+t+'<\/strong>-'+n.text()))})
```

Comment: I just tried using the bookmarklet, but it doesn't put the correct number in the card. I'm actually not sure where it's coming from - for example, a user story with ID 8652 shows "51" on the card; "14550" shows "56". I tried changing a few of the values in the bookmarklet, but strangely, nothing has any effect - the behavior doesn't change at all, which is weird, considering I changed (5,999) to (1,1) just to see what it would do, and it didn't do anything. Or I changed witTitle to witID, also with no effect. 
Anyone else have and or solve this issue?